# How to combine time template for a specific locate and 12h/24h format from phone settings

Tags: android, location

I have a specific problem on my project:
I need to combine a time template for specific locate (user can choose any locate in general and this locate different from system) and 12h/24h format, which user choose in settings.
So steps are:

1. Get a list of time templates for specific locate
2. Choose a template for 12h/24h format from the list